# Print subcategories in Twig template engine

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have the next data structure in the array.

```
$a = [['id' => 1, 'parent_id' => 0], ['id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 0], ['id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 2], ['id' =>  4, 'parent_id' => 3]];
```

I have horizontal menu with all main categories (with 'parent_id' = 0).
The next code will print all main categories.

```
{% for dept in common.departments %}
                            {% if dept.parent_id == 0 %}
                                <li><a href="/{{ dept.seo_title }}/{{ dept.id }}/dept" class="black">{{ dept.title }}</a><!-- for subdepartments --></li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
```

How can I print all subcategories in the tree format?

Example:

```
Dept 1  Dept4  
 Dept5   Dept2  
  Dept7  Dept3
```

Changed:

```
<div class="clearfix">                      
                    {% macro displayChildren(departments, parent_id, deep) %}
                        {% for dept in departments %}
                            {% if dept.parent_id == parent_id %}
                                <li><a href="/{{ dept.seo_title }}/{{ dept.id }}/dept" class="black" style="margin-left: {{ deep * 10 }}px;">{{ dept.title }}</a></li>
                                {{ _self.displayChildren(departments, dept.id, deep + 1) }}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endmacro %}

                    {% for dept in common.departments %}
                        {% if (dept.parent_id == 0) %}
                        <li><a href="/{{ dept.seo_title }}/{{ dept.id }}/dept" class="black">{{ dept.title }}</a><div class="dropdown-menu"><ol class="nav">{{ _self.displayChildren(common.departments, dept.id, 0) }}</ol></div></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a macro and recursivity should work:

```
{{ _self.displayChildren(departments, 0, 0, '') }}

{% macro displayChildren(departments, parent_id, deep, concat) %}
    {% for dept in departments %}
        {%- if dept.parent_id == parent_id %}
            {% set subconcat = (concat ? concat ~ '-':'') ~ 'dept' ~ dept.id %}
            {{ subconcat }}
            {{ _self.displayChildren(departments, dept.id, deep + 1, subconcat) }}
        {% endif -%}
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Displaying:

```
<div style="margin-left: 0px;">dept1</div>
<div style="margin-left: 0px;">dept2</div>
<div style="margin-left: 20px;">dept2-dept3</div>
<div style="margin-left: 40px;">dept2-dept3-dept4</div>
```

Or interpreted:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I did it. You are genius! How can I save the seo_title? I need tree-structure of seo titles. from the lowest subcategory to the main. /subcategory2-subcategory1-maincategory/ ?

Comment: Oh ok, then you add a fourth parameter containing the concatenation of the whole path. Let me edit.

Comment: I edited without reversing the order. To reverse it, use `{{ _self.displayChildren(departments, 0, 0, '')|split("\n")|reverse|join("\n") }}` instead of the first line.

Comment: did it. looks great! is it possible to distinguish all parent departments if I know, that the user selected some subdept? i may be dept4 in your example. so, we need to add underline to dept4 link and the all parent links. is is possible with Twig?

Comment: I let you add a fifth parameter to the macro containing the base dept. Then, replace `{{ subconcat }}` by `{% if subconcat[0:basedept|length] == basedept %}{{ subconcat }}{% endif %}` and this should be good. I won't get further now, please ask new questions if needed. Thanks!